# Compare variance across time

Tags: anova, variance, t-test, repeated-measures, biostatistics

I have an analysis question. Unfortunately my biostats collaborator is no longer involved in the project.

We have a dataset of n=6 people. the study was terminated early due to covid but we are still required to report results despite the very small number of subjects. For each subject we have measured our variable of interest weekly. Subjects then began a 3-month intervention and continued the weekly survey. We want to know if variability in our outcome changed with the intervention. In our SAP my collaborator wrote, “we will compare weekly variance estimates of variable of interest (frequency of a specific behavior occurring)” to test this question. This is asked by a single question where the subject indicates the number or times the behavior occurred during the past week. This question is asked for 16-weeks. The first 4 are pre intervention, the final 12 weeks are during an intervention. This is the only behavior we are asking about regarding variability/variance.

It’s not clear to me how to do this statistically given the repeated measure design.

Comment: By "frequency of a specific behavior occurring" do you mean yes/no, the behavior occurred/didn't, or the number of times a specific behavior occurred during each week? Or perhaps per day or per hour within each week, or...? Is there more than 1 behavior in question? The more details you can provide about the study (nature of behavior, how often it was observed), the better any answer is likely to be. Please provide such details by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: Added requested info

Answer (score 1):

As you only have one weekly report of the number of behaviors, you don't have the usual measure of variance within a week for an individual. I suspect that the statistician had in mind a [Poisson regression model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression).

For such a model, the variance in the number of counts *equals* the number of counts, so modeling the counts is the same as modeling the variance. It's possible to test that assumption of variance = mean, and use a negative binomial or a "quasi-Poisson" model instead if the assumption isn't tenable, as explained in the above link and in many pages on this site.

There is no problem accounting for the repeated-measure design. Most simply, with only 6 individuals you can include `individual` as a categorical, fixed-effect predictor in your model to account for differences in baseline counts. You could also include interactions of `individual` with `intervention` to allow for differences in responses to the `intervention`. An alternative would be to account for `individual` with a random term or terms in a [mixed model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model). Your sample of 6 individuals is at the point where either fixed or random effects might be used.

What isn't clear from your description is how the effect of `intervention` was going to be teased apart from `time`. Unless the `intervention` has an immediate and constant effect, the `intervention` would presumably change the trajectory over time of the behavior. Thus simply averaging pre- and post-intervention counts per week might not use your data fairly.

My guess is that a simple plot of your counts over time for each individual, with some simple smooth curve for each as produced by [LOESS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression), will provide useful hints.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! This is helpful. This biostatistician did know how we were measuring it (once per week) but unfortunately was vague on their analysis plan

Comment: A follow up as I read this again if by saying “simply averaging pre- and post-intervention counts per week might not use your data fairly” you mean take all our weekly pre intervention frequency counts to create one average score and all our weekly intervention counts to make a single average score - that was not the plan. Then intent was to use all of the data for each week - so compare variances across all 16 weeks of data.

Comment: @Jamie yes, following the entire time course as you planned is clearly the best way to go. Ideally there would be no time trend over the 4 pre-intervention observations and then a clear trend thereafter. You might want to investigate [`change-point`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/change-point?tab=Votes) methods. Unfortunately, without a control no-intervention group, it will be hard to establish that the intervention was responsible for the change.

Comment: @Jamie one other thought: might the statistician have meant to evaluate the variance _among_ the participants? I doubt it, but that is another way one might interpret your quote from the statistician's plan.